# Filter various columns with vectors using "on" with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to do several filters at once, as efficiently as possible with data.table. Is there a way to achieve this with "on".

I need it to be in data.table because of efficiency (I have to perform millions of filters + summaries on a dataset)

This code with dplyr should be done in data.table. (hopefully with the same structure I already tried, i might be missing something).

```
data("iris")

iris %>% filter(Sepal.Length %in% c(5, 6.2), 
         Species %in% c("setosa", "virginica", "versicolor"))
```

I tried,

```
DT <- setDT(iris)

DT[.(c(5, 6.2), c("setosa", "virginica", "versicolor")),  on = c( "Sepal.Length", "Species")]
```

I know I can perform one filter and then another, but the code is slower.

I get a the warning:

> In as.data.table.list(i) :   Item 1 is of size 2 but maximum size is 3
>   (recycled leaving a remainder of 1 items)

So as I understand, it filters 5 with "setosa", 6.2 with "virginica" and again 5 with "versicolor".

Comment: r u looking for `DT[CJ(Sepal.Length=c(5, 6.2), Species=c("setosa", "virginica", "versicolor")), on = c( "Sepal.Length", "Species")]`?

Comment: Why not just `iris[Sepal.Length %in% c(5, 6.2) & Species %in% c("setosa", "virginica", "versicolor") ,]` ? Or is that you mean by 'one filter and then another'?

Comment: `%chin%` will be faster for Species column

Comment: Is %chin% faster than %in% for integers? I.e., would you recommend transforming to character if millones of %in% have to be performed?

Comment: %in% for integers and %chin% for character

Answer (score 1):

As @thelatemail put it in a comment, you just bring everything you have in your dplyr `filter` to the `i` portion of `data.table` (remember: data.table works like DT[filter_conditions, do_stuff, by_group] == `DT[i, j, by]`).

So it will be

```
iris[Sepal.Length %in% c(5, 6.2) & Species %chin% c("setosa", "virginica", "versicolor"), ]
```

Two additional things to notice:

- If you want to filter `Sepal.Length`s that are *between* 5 and 6.2, you can chnage the `%in%` by `%between%` or `%inrange%`. See `?between` and `?inrange`
- Use `%chin%` (ch-aracter in) to check belonging in character vectors, it's much faster than plain `%in%`. See `?chmatch`